# Ansible not using correct vars when specifying?

Tags: python, yaml, ansible

I'm having some issues with my ansible playbook not adding in the right variables. Here is the task.

```
 #Change name: to be the name of whatever group you want to add
 - name: Add new group if necessary
   group: 
    name: "{{ group_name }}" 
    state: present



# Change name: to be the name of the user you wish to add.
 - name: Manage user accounts
   user: name={{ item }} state=present group={{ group_name }}
   with_items: "{{ users }} "
```

Here are the variable files

```
---
users:
 - test1
 - test2
 - test3

group_name:
 - developers
```

For some reason when I am running this it creates the group and names it this 
'developers'

Then, the add user part of the play actually is looking for a totally different group name just [developers]

See failed output.

```
PLAY [users] ******************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [172.17.51.202]

TASK: [user-manage | Add new group if necessary] ******************************
changed: [172.17.51.202]

TASK: [user-manage | Manage user accounts] ************************************
failed: [172.17.51.202] => (item=test1) => {"failed": true, "item": "test1"}
msg: Group [developers] does not exist
failed: [172.17.51.202] => (item=test2) => {"failed": true, "item": "test2"}
msg: Group [developers] does not exist
failed: [172.17.51.202] => (item=test3) => {"failed": true, "item": "test3"}
msg: Group [developers] does not exist

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Here is the group it actually creates. 
I cannot figure out why they are both looking for different variables and neither one is actually the correct one that I have specified.

Any ideas?

In response to Petro:

I changed it from a list to a singular variable

```
---
users:
 - test1
 - test2
 - test3

group_name: developers
```

I still get this error

```
failed: [172.17.51.202] => (item=test1) => {"failed": true, "item": "test1"}
msg: Group [developers] does not exist
failed: [172.17.51.202] => (item=test2) => {"failed": true, "item": "test2"}
msg: Group [developers] does not exist
failed: [172.17.51.202] => (item=test3) => {"failed": true, "item": "test3"}
msg: Group [developers] does not exist

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

So that didn't work. Any other ideas?

EDIT 2:

Petro that actually did work. Sorry. I had messed up. Your's was the right answer.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made "group_name" a list instead of single value.  Change your vars file to:

```
group_name: developers
```

and it should work

Comment: I updated my original comment to include your advice. Still does not work. See above.